# How can I layout a list of IPython.display.Audio objects in a Jupyter notebook?

Tags: python, ipython, jupyter-notebook

I have a list of audio data that I want to display in a Jupyter notebook using `IPython.display.Audio` such that these controls are flowing from left to right next to one another. I tried using `ipywidgets.HBox` but I get the an error since `IPython.display.Audio` is not an instance of a `Widget`.

My list of of audio data looks like the following, where `y` is the audio data and `sr` is the sampling rate.

```
data = [(y1, sr1), (y2, sr2), ..., (yN, srN)]
```

What I tried to do is something like the following.

```
audio_widgets = [display.Audio(audio[0], sr=audio[1]) for audio in data]
audio_hbox = widgets.HBox(audio_widgets) # TraitError happens here
```

I get the following error.

```
TraitError: Element of the 'children' trait of a HBox instance must be a Widget, but a value of <IPython.lib.display.Audio object> <class 'IPython.lib.display.Audio'> was specified.
```

One way to get the audio displays to show is to simply show them one above the other (which takes up a lot of vertical space when there are a lot of audio data).

```
for audio in data:
     audio_widget = display.Audio(audio[0], sr=audio[1])
     display(audio_widget)
```

Any ideas on how I can control the layout display of audio controls?

Answer (score 7):

You could display the `Audio`s into [output widgets](https://ipywidgets.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/Output%20Widget.html). Anything that displays nicely in a notebook will also display nicely in an output widget. You can direct output to the widget using a context manager, see example code below.

```
from IPython.display import Audio, display
from ipywidgets import widgets

audio_widgets = []
for (audio, sample_rate) in data:
    out = widgets.Output()
    with out:
        display(Audio(data=audio, rate=sample_rate))
    audio_widgets.append(out)
widgets.HBox(audio_widgets)
```

You could also `print` or `display` something else into the same output widget beside the `Audio` - possibly to have a label next to each audio piece.

This is a very late answer but whatever)).